# PHP Upload Problem

Tags: php, image, file-upload, gd

I created a script that resizes images based on their ratio. For some reason, it keeps echoing "Failed" and is not moving the resized thumbnail to the directory I have set. The directory is a valid path, so I must have done something wrong when creating an image with PHP.

```
$set_width  = $params['width'];
$set_height = $params['height'];

if($filetype == "image/pjpeg" || $filetype == "image/jpeg") {
  $new_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filetmp);     
} elseif($filetype == "image/x-png" || $filetype == "image/png") {  
  $new_image = imagecreatefrompng($filetmp);
} elseif($filetype == "image/gif") {
  $new_image = imagecreatefromgif($filetmp);
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filetmp);

$ratio = $width / $height;

if($width != $set_width || $height != $set_height) {
  if($ratio > 1)
  {
    $set_height = $set_width / $ratio;
  }
  else
  {
    $set_height = $set_width;
    $set_width  = $set_width * $ratio;
  }

  $resized = imagecreatetruecolor($set_width, $set_height);
  $rename  = $folder . '_' . time() . mt_rand(1,99) . '.' . end($fileext);

  imagecopyresampled($resized, $new_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $set_width, $set_height, $width, $height);
  imagejpeg($resized, "$dirpath/$rename", 100);
  imageDestroy($resized);
  imageDestroy($new_image);

  if(move_uploaded_file($resized, "$dirpath/$rename")) {
    return $rename;
  } else {
    echo 'failed';
  }
} else { 
  $rename  = $folder . '_' . time() . mt_rand(1,99) . '.' . end($fileext);
  if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "$dirpath/$rename")) {
    return $rename;
  } else {
    echo 'failed 2';
  }
}
```

Comment: So, add more debugging output, beside this uninformative "Failed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't move the resource returned by `imagecreatetruecolor()`

The GD library creates the image in memory, it doesn't alter the file you used in `imagecreatefrom*()`

You use one of the GD functions to save the image...

- [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) - Output image to browser or file
- [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) - Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file
- [`imagegif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) - Output image to browser or file

etc...

You've used the correct line

```
imagejpeg($resized, "$dirpath/$rename", 100);
```

You are trying to save the GD resource `$resized` using move_upload_file. `$resized` isn't a file name, so the `move_uploaded_file()` fails.

You don't need that call at all, the file should already be saved at `$dirpath/$rename` by the `imagejpeg()` call.

Comment: Jacob,  I have used the imagejpeg function as you can see in my script.  For some reason it isn't saving the image?

Comment: My apologies... you don't need the move_uploaded_file at all then... You are trying to move a GD resource, after isn't been created where you want to move it to anyway.

Comment: For some reason even when I take out the move_uploaded_file it still isn't moving the resized version of the image.

Comment: Check the return value of imagejpeg, it returns false on failure.

Answer (score 0):

You should check permissions of the directory, keep in mind your web server may be running under a different user then you.

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions if you need to learn about *nix permissions.

Comment: The permissions of the directory are fine.  When I set the script to NOT resize the image, it works fine..

Comment: you should check certain error message first. And go check for permissions only if there is a problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of `set_width` and `set_height` in `$resized = imagecreatetruecolor($set_width, $set_height);` Maybe its sending a null value